# Cake - Getting the ID from the model we just inserted?

Tags: cakephp

When I'm googling, I found that everyone is suggesting `getLastInsertID()` to get the ID of the model we just saved / inserted.

But what if during the split millisecond before that method run, another user inserted a new data?

Will the method return the ID of the data that was inserted by that another user?

For clarification, here's an example:

```
$this->Post->save($this->request->data); //Data saved as ID 1
//During this split millisecond, someone else save a data with ID 2
$this->Post->getLastInsertID(); //will this return 1 or 2?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, i think `$this->Post->getLastInsertID();` in your question would return `1` even in case some other user saved the data, that's because its per-connection. It is affected only by statements issued within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements issued by other clients. So that would mean using `$this->Post->getLastInsertID();` would be safer in case you mentioned as well.

Comment: $this->Post->id would do the same as is much more succinct.